# how to boot into Windows XP?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I am not finding a way to boot into Windows XP in my PC.
This is the sequence of installation I have done in my PC.

1. Ubuntu 13.04
2. Windows XP(formed Dual-Boot)
3. Windows 8 installed( Not formatted Ubuntu an XP partitions)
4. CentOS 6.4 installed

Thats the way & Sequence of installation  I have done in my PC. After that I felt Windows 8 is crap(under my needs) and formatted that drive.

I have restored Ubuntu GRUB menu with boot-repair.Now I can boot into Ubuntu and CentOS but I cant boot into Windows XP . I am getting the Windows 8 screen and system restarting automatically when I boot into XP from GRUB boot loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really a Windows question.

Windows installs all boot loaders to the active partition or boot flagged partition. So the Windows 8 boot loader bootmgr replaced ntldr in the partition boot sector - PBR to boot. And it then uses the BCD to know what to boot not the boot.ini file.

You need to run chkdsk from the XP install disk and remove bootmgr & /BCD. You need ntldr and boot.ini which still should be in your XP partition.

If you only overwrote PBR,you may be able to use testdisk to restore backup PBR. You can use testdisk to compare PBR (dump command) 
and see if in plain text the backup has ntldr not bootmgr.
Instructions
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Menu_Analyse
As described, it has an option to "Recover NTFS boot sector from its backup"
If Backup BS isn't available, choose RebuildBS.